# Динамическая передача данных из js объекта в html, javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, javascript-events

Пишу подобие маленькой игры. Создала js модель, в которой есть три класса, Rabbit, Hunter и Forest. Реализована и визуализирована подписка и отписка объектов охотников от объекта заяц, добавление-удаление охотников и перемещение зайца. Нужно сделать так, чтобы координаты перемещения зайца, которые видны только в консоли, отображались в html, там где написано Rabbit Jonny moved to (...). Я пробовала сделать это через get-свойство, но координаты в таком случае создаются неизменными. Кроме того, не могу понять, почему даже в консоли не работает функция photo(). С ней в идеале задумка такая, чтобы при каждом нажатии кнопки "photo rabbit" все имеющиеся охотники делали рандомный выстрел и при попадании в зайца появлялась надпись "Hunter[имя] made new photo with rabbit". Код js следующий:

```js
'use strict';

class Rabbit {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.hunters = [];
  }

  on(hunter) {
    this.hunters.push(hunter);
  }

  off(hunter) {
    this.hunters = this.hunters.filter((cb) => cb !== hunter);
  }

  move() {
    this.x = (Math.random() * 1000 / 2).toFixed(0);
    this.y = (Math.random() * 1000 / 2).toFixed(0);
    this.hunters.forEach((cb) => cb(this.x, this.y));
    console.log(`Rabbit ${this.name} moved to (${this.x}, ${this.y}).`);
    return jump();
  }
}

class Hunter {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.xCoord = 0;
    this.yCoord = 0;
    this.watch = this.watch.bind(this);
    this.photo = this.photo.bind(this);
  }

  watch(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    console.log(`${this.name} sees that rabbit Jonny moved to (${this.x}, ${this.y}).`);
  }

  photo(rabbit) {
    this.xCoord = (Math.random() * 1000 / 2).toFixed(0);
    this.yCoord = (Math.random() * 1000 / 2).toFixed(0);
    let photoSpace = (this.xCoord - rabbit.x) ** 2 + (this.yCoord - rabbit.y) ** 2;
    let result = "looser";

    if (photoSpace <= 1600) {
      result = `Hunter ${this._name} made photo with Jonny!`;
    }
    console.log(result);
  }
}

class Forest {
  constructor() {
    this.rabbit = new Rabbit("Jonny");
    this.hunters = [];
    this.hunterNum = 1;
  }

  addHunter() {
    let name = `Hunter ${this.hunterNum++}`
    let hunter = new Hunter(name, this);
    this.hunters.push(hunter);
    this.rabbit.on(hunter.watch);
    return hunter;
  }

  removeHunter(hunter) {
    this.rabbit.off(hunter.watch);
  }

  makePhoto(rabbit) {
    this.hunters.forEach(hunter => hunter.photo(rabbit));
  }
}

const forest = new Forest();
let rabbit = forest.rabbit;
let moveRabbit = document.getElementById("rabbit");

function jump() {
  moveRabbit.style.top = parseInt(rabbit.x) + 'px';
  moveRabbit.style.left = parseInt(rabbit.y) + 'px';
}

move.addEventListener("click", () => rabbitJump());

function rabbitJump() {
  return rabbit.move();
}

add.addEventListener("click", () => addNewHunter());

function addNewHunter() {
  let hunter = forest.addHunter();
  let defaultHunter = document.createElement('div');
  defaultHunter.id = hunter.name;
  defaultHunter.innerHTML = '<div class="hunter">' +
    '<img src="owl.jpg" alt="hunter">' +
    '<span class="hunterName">' + defaultHunter.id + '</span>' +
    '<div class="rabbitCoords">' +
    '<p> Rabbit Jonny moved to (...) </p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';
  huntersContainer.appendChild(defaultHunter);
}

remove.addEventListener("click", () => removeLastHunter());

function removeLastHunter() {
  let hunter = forest.hunters.pop();
  let hunterID = document.getElementById(hunter.name);
  console.log(hunterID);
  huntersContainer.removeChild(hunterID);
  forest.removeHunter(hunter);
}

makePhoto.addEventListener("click", makeNewPhoto());

function makeNewPhoto() {
  /*....*/
  return forest.makePhoto();

}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="game-holder">
    <div class="forest">
      <img src="rabbit.png" id="rabbit" alt="Rabbit Jonny">
    </div>
    <div class="hunter-holder">
      <div class="hunters" id="huntersContainer">
      </div>
      <div class="button-holder">
        <button id="add" class="button">Add Hunter</button>
        <button id="remove" class="button">Remove Hunter</button>
        <button id="move" class="button">Rabbits move</button>
        <button id="makePhoto" class="button">Photo rabbit:)</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Нужно сделать так, чтобы координаты перемещения зайца, которые видны только в консоли, отображались в html

Так как `forest` имеет при себе `rabbit` (`this.rabbit = new Rabbit("Jonny");`) то мы можем обратиться к `x` и `y` по пути `forest.rabbit`

> Кроме того, не могу понять, почему даже в консоли не работает функция photo().

В установке события `makePhoto.addEventListener("click", makeNewPhoto());` происходит непосредственный вызов `makeNewPhoto` а не его передача в виде аргумента.

Если текущая область видимости неважна то стоит передавать функцию без обёртки `makePhoto.addEventListener("click", makeNewPhoto);`. В таком случае `this` в функции `makeNewPhoto` будет иметь ссылку на инициатор события `makePhoto`, так же в функцию будет передан объект `event` первым аргументом.

Иначе можно обернуть в анонимную функцию `makePhoto.addEventListener("click", ()=>makeNewPhoto());`

К прочтению: [Деструктуализация](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring), [Шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), [Стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```js
'use strict';

class Rabbit {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.hunters = [];
  }

  on(hunter) {
    this.hunters.push(hunter);
  }

  off(hunter) {
    this.hunters = this.hunters.filter((cb) => cb !== hunter);
  }

  move() {
    this.x = (Math.random() * 1000 / 2).toFixed(0);
    this.y = (Math.random() * 1000 / 2).toFixed(0);
    this.hunters.forEach((cb) => cb(this.x, this.y));
    console.log(`Rabbit ${this.name} moved to (${this.x}, ${this.y}).`);
    return jump();
  }
}

class Hunter {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.xCoord = 0;
    this.yCoord = 0;
    this.watch = this.watch.bind(this);
    this.photo = this.photo.bind(this);
  }

  watch(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    console.log(`${this.name} sees that rabbit Jonny moved to (${this.x}, ${this.y}).`);
    if (this.node) {
      hunterViewUpdate(this)
    }
  }

  photo(rabbit) {
    this.xCoord = (Math.random() * 1000 / 2).toFixed(0);
    this.yCoord = (Math.random() * 1000 / 2).toFixed(0);
    let photoSpace = (this.xCoord - rabbit.x) ** 2 + (this.yCoord - rabbit.y) ** 2;
    let result = "looser";

    if (photoSpace <= 1600) {
      result = `Hunter ${this._name} made photo with Jonny!`;
    }
    console.log(result);
  }
}

class Forest {
  constructor() {
    this.rabbit = new Rabbit("Jonny");
    this.hunters = [];
    this.hunterNum = 1;
  }

  addHunter() {
    let name = `Hunter ${this.hunterNum++}`
    let hunter = new Hunter(name, this);
    this.hunters.push(hunter);
    hunter.watch(this.rabbit.x, this.rabbit.y);
    this.rabbit.on(hunter.watch);
    return hunter;
  }

  removeHunter(hunter) {
    this.rabbit.off(hunter.watch);
  }

  makePhoto(rabbit) {
    this.hunters.forEach(hunter => hunter.photo(rabbit));
  }
}

const forest = new Forest();
let rabbit = forest.rabbit;
let moveRabbit = document.getElementById("rabbit");

function jump() {
  moveRabbit.style.top = parseInt(rabbit.x) + 'px';
  moveRabbit.style.left = parseInt(rabbit.y) + 'px';
}

move.addEventListener("click", () => rabbitJump());

function rabbitJump() {
  return rabbit.move();
}

add.addEventListener("click", () => addNewHunter());

function addNewHunter() {
  let hunter = forest.addHunter();
  let defaultHunter = document.createElement('div');
  hunter.node = defaultHunter;
  defaultHunter.id = hunter.name;
  hunterViewUpdate(hunter);
  huntersContainer.appendChild(defaultHunter);
}

function hunterViewUpdate(hunter) {
  let defaultHunter = hunter.node;
  let { x, y } = hunter;
  defaultHunter.innerHTML = '<div class="hunter">' +
    '<img src="owl.jpg" alt="hunter">' +
    '<span class="hunterName">' + defaultHunter.id + '</span>' +
    '<div class="rabbitCoords">' +
    '<p> Rabbit Jonny moved to ('+x+', '+y+') </p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';
}

remove.addEventListener("click", () => removeLastHunter());

function removeLastHunter() {
  let hunter = forest.hunters.pop();
  let hunterID = document.getElementById(hunter.name);
  console.log(hunterID);
  huntersContainer.removeChild(hunterID);
  forest.removeHunter(hunter);
}

makePhoto.addEventListener("click", makeNewPhoto);

function makeNewPhoto() {
  /*....*/
  return forest.makePhoto(rabbit);

}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="game-holder">
    <div class="forest">
      <img src="rabbit.png" id="rabbit" alt="Rabbit Jonny">
    </div>
    <div class="hunter-holder">
      <div class="hunters" id="huntersContainer">
      </div>
      <div class="button-holder">
        <button id="add" class="button">Add Hunter</button>
        <button id="remove" class="button">Remove Hunter</button>
        <button id="move" class="button">Rabbits move</button>
        <button id="makePhoto" class="button">Photo rabbit:)</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если обращаться к координатам через forest.rabbit, то они создаются вместе с новым объектом охотника и не изменяются. Я имела  в виду,  что нужен какой-то метод, который позволит в каждого охотника передавать координаты зайца, после его каждого перемещения. Например, есть три охотника, кролик сделал движение и у всех троих появилась надпись "Rabbit Jonny moved to (someX, someY)".

Comment: @АлисаГулий обновил код

Comment: @АлисаГулий если ответ подходит, следует пометить его как верный.